# Selenium - how to add latest chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing Selenium training and my chrome browser is Version 116.0.5845.140 on the Mac.

I couldn't find Chrome driver exe for this version instead it's providing like below https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

When I go to the driver page it shows the application file and not the exe file.
I am not sure how to configure it access from Selenium.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/abc/Documents/chromedriver");
```

Error during execution of application.

INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: chromedriver located at /Users/abc/Documents/chromedriver, but invalid
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/

when I download from dirvers page it has file like this
[image]

Not sure how to call this file

Comment: That page literally gives you the list of URLs for all the v116 chrome drivers for all common operating systems so... did you download the one you needed? Sure, they're text links, but presumably you know how to copy-paste =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans can you see image I attached in Answers. That is file in driver downloaded.

Comment: Then put that in your post. Don't post it as answer and then delete it again. Also there is no such thing as a "exe" on MacOS, that's a windows executable. MacOS executables are applications, which your screenshot clearly shows it is.

Comment: really sorry if any misunderstood. I was not able to paste screen shot in comment so that's why I put it in answer section.
Thank you so much for your answers. I will find it.

Comment: Just click [edit] and put it in your post?

Answer (score 0):

on your screenshot is not the driver, on the screenshot you added the chrome installer

[Drivers](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)
[arm64 driver](https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip)
[x86_64 driver](https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/mac-x64/chromedriver-mac-x64.zip)

selenium 4.11.2 provides DriverManager that automatically find latest chrome driver
[Automate browser management](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#automated-browser-management)

[driver implementation](https://github.com/DimaBerezovskyi/simple-python-selenium-framework/blob/main/src/utils/driver_util.py)

Comment: Thank you for your activitiy, but could you update your 'Driver implementation' link, please? I'm getting now the issue as: '404 - page not found' using your [driver implementation](https://github.com/DimaBerezovskyi/pytest-python-selenium-framework/blob/main/src/utils/driver_util.py) link.